# repository pattern variations?

Tags: design-patterns, repository-pattern

Based on the following url, a repository pattern is basically a layer of repository objects that are used to encapsulate data access:

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html

For example, a UserRepository object would have a GetUsers() method like this

```
public User GetUsers()
{
   return context.Users;
}
```

Is that all there is to the Repository pattern or is there more to it?  Are there any named variations of this pattern?  For example, I think I encountered someone in the past who asserted that this pattern involved generic/dynamic CRUD for entities.  For example, since CRUD is a fundamental and repeatable pattern a repository pattern would provide CRUD functionality dynamically for any/all entities.  I guess something like this:  new Repository().Read().  Is there a name for this variation of the Repository pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Repository Pattern is simply about decoupling from the specific data storage implementation(s). CRUD would absolutely fit under that umbrella, and commonly does.

The most important thing is just to decided precisely which operation are needed for which business objects. You don't need to expose all CRUD operations for everything.

Here is a pretty good article with sample code for a standard Repository Pattern implementation. YMMV. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526874/Repository-pattern-done-right

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know the name of the other pattern I described in my post?:  var users = new Repository<User>().ReadAll()  I'm sure it can be described by one or more design patterns although Repository pattern may not be the best way to describe it.  To recap, this implementation is based on the fact that all entities will share a certain subset of generic/repeatable CRUD methods.

Comment: ReadAll() or GetAll() would still fit under the umbrella of Repository Pattern. You could even fit methods that have query parameters like GetWhere(Predicate) or similar.

Comment: Regarding my last comment, I'll just refer to it as a "dynamic repository" pattern unless someone else can identify a more formal design pattern associated with this implementation